# Why can't I find the certificate to sign the ClickOnce manifest?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, manifest

I had to make some changes in an application done by a guy who worked on a project before me. I asked him for the sources and he gave them to me. The problem is that when I try to build (even before making any changes) I get the following error:

"Error 1    Unable to find manifest signing certificate in the certificate store."

[image]

What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: The problem is that the project needs to be deployed with ClickOnce... I can't really uncheck that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is expecting the certificate that was used to sign the manifest. Either provide the certificate or sign it with your own certificate. It appears you have the solution "Sign the ClickOnce manifest" checked ( I can't tell horrible unclear image ) the simple solution is not to sign it or provide your own certificate

Comment: How do I create a certificate?

Answer (score 5):

Well you need a [code signing certificate](http://www.verisign.com/code-signing/) or simply press the "Create a test certificate" button. Also do not forget to put the below into the 'Timestamp server URL' box:

```
http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll
```

Answer (score 4):

Go to the signing tab of the project properties and unchecked "Sign the ClickOnce manifests".

Hope that helps...........

Comment: @TechGiant.thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unchecking "Sign the ClickOnce manifests"?  Does this project need to be deployed via ClickOnce?